# Gradient descent in Java

Tags: java, artificial-intelligence, gradient-descent

I've recently started the AI-Class at Coursera and I've a question related to my implementation of the gradient descent algorithm.

Here's my current implementation (I actually just "translated" the mathematical expressions into Java code):

```
    public class GradientDescent {

    private static final double TOLERANCE = 1E-11;
    
    private double theta0;
    private double theta1;
    
    public double getTheta0() {
        return theta0;
    }
    
    public double getTheta1() {
        return theta1;
    }
    
    public GradientDescent(double theta0, double theta1) {
         this.theta0 = theta0;
         this.theta1 = theta1;
    }
    
    public double getHypothesisResult(double x){
        return theta0 + theta1*x;
    }
    
    private double getResult(double[][] trainingData, boolean enableFactor){
        double result = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < trainingData.length; i++) {
            result = (getHypothesisResult(trainingData[i][0]) - trainingData[i][1]);
            if (enableFactor) result = result*trainingData[i][0]; 
        }
        return result;
    }
    
    public void train(double learningRate, double[][] trainingData){
        int iteration = 0;
        double delta0, delta1;
        do{
            iteration++;
            System.out.println("SUBS: " + (learningRate*((double) 1/trainingData.length))*getResult(trainingData, false));
            double temp0 = theta0 - learningRate*(((double) 1/trainingData.length)*getResult(trainingData, false));
            double temp1 = theta1 - learningRate*(((double) 1/trainingData.length)*getResult(trainingData, true));
            delta0 = theta0-temp0; delta1 = theta1-temp1;
            theta0 = temp0; theta1 = temp1;
        }while((Math.abs(delta0) + Math.abs(delta1)) > TOLERANCE);
        System.out.println(iteration);
    }
}
```

The code works quite well but only if I choose an very little alpha, here called learningRate. If it's higher than 0.00001, it diverges.

Do you have any suggestions on how to optimize the implementation, or an explanation for the "Alpha-Issue" and a possible solution for it?

**Update:**

Here's the main including some sample inputs:

```
private static final double[][] TDATA = {{200, 20000},{300, 41000},{900, 141000},{800, 41000},{400, 51000},{500, 61500}};

public static void main(String[] args) {
    GradientDescent gd = new GradientDescent(0,0);
    gd.train(0.00001, TDATA);
    System.out.println("THETA0: " + gd.getTheta0() + " - THETA1: " + gd.getTheta1());
    System.out.println("PREDICTION: " + gd.getHypothesisResult(300));
}
```

The mathematical expression of gradient descent is as follows:

[image]

Comment: You should probably provide some example data/input, in a `main` method, and maybe a backlink to the forumlas that you "translated".

Comment: I've updated the question and I've also found a little issue. After fixing it, I'm now able to set the learning rate to 0.0001. But I think it's still quite low but way better than before.

Comment: Which of the Coursera ML / AI classes was it? Stanford's Machine Learning?

Comment: Yes, it was the Stanford Machine Learning course. It was interesting in the beginning but I didn't like the exercises in Octave (they felt way to generic) so I started to implement the algorithms in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To solve this issue, it's necessary to normalize the data  with this formular: (Xi-mu)/s.
Xi is the current training set value, mu the average of values in the current column and s the maximum value minus the minimum value of the current column. This formula will get the training data approximately into a range between -1 and 1 which allowes to choose higher learning rates and gradient descent to converge faster.
But it's afterwards necessary to denormalize the predicted result.

Answer (score 3):

```
private double getResult(double[][] trainingData, boolean enableFactor){
double result = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < trainingData.length; i++) {
    result = (getHypothesisResult(trainingData[i][0]) - trainingData[i][1]);
    if (enableFactor) result = result*trainingData[i][0]; 
}
return result;
```

In this func. result variable overwritten each iteration, the old value being lost. When inputing the values only the last item on array is calculating. Rest of them dont matter.

Comment: You are right! Thank your for the suggestion! Turned out to be an very slow stochastic gradient descent...still functional but slow because all samples will be processed to update the parameters with just one sample.

Answer (score -1):

You should use java.math.BigDecimal for your arithematic operations.
double has its rounding-off issues while performing any arithematic.

Comment: That's a wild guess, and I'm close to downvoting this: Just replacing `double` with `BigDecimal` will not necessarily solve the issue, which might (!) be completely unrelated to the precision....